# C Insertion Sort - Implementation

Tags: c, list, sorting, linked-list, insertion-sort

I've just started programming in C and need a bit of help with my implementation of Insertion Sort.

I am doing a **C list insertion sort.**

**Here is the peseudocode for it, which I want to convert into C**

> otherwise
>              use a loop to find the last item in the list which should precede the new person
>              set the new person's "next" link to point to whatever follows this list item
>
> set the "next" link of this item to point to the new person
>
> return the (start of the) list

**Here is my partial implementation of my pseudocode**

```
else    
      {
         for (int i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
         {

        people = people -> next;
        if (people -> next == NULL) return people;
     } //for
      }//else

       return pointer;    
}
```

**Here is my full method:**

```
struct person *insert_sorted (struct person *people, char *name, int age) {
//create a new space for the new person
  struct person *pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
   // check it succeeded
    if(pointer == NULL)
    { 
     printf("The program could not allocate memory ");
      exit(-1);
    }
     // set the data for the new person
      strcpy(pointer -> name, name);
      pointer -> age = age;
      pointer -> next = people;
     // if the current list is empty
      if (people == NULL)
      {
        // set the new person's "next" link to point to the current list"
    pointer -> next = people;
    // return a pointer to the new person
    return pointer;
      }
else    
      {
         for (int i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
         {

        people = people -> next;
        if (people -> next == NULL) return people;
     } //for
      }//else

       return pointer;    
}
```

*If you need the full program coude, let me know.*

Thank you!

Sarah :)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What's the problem?

Comment: Hey Paddy, sorry for not being clear enough. My problem is that I am not sure how to implement my algorithm (1st box) as C code. 2nd box is my attempt at making an insertion sort, but it is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before inserting the element into the list *people you should check the the correct position.
try this:

```
struct person *insert_sorted (struct person *people, char *name, int age) {

//create a new space for the new person
struct person *pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
// check it succeeded
if(pointer == NULL)
{ 
 printf("The program could not allocate memory ");
  exit(-1);
}
 // set the data for the new person
  strcpy(pointer -> name, name);
  pointer -> age = age;
struct person *cursor = people;
struct person *previous = people;
if(people == NULL){
    pointer->next = NULL;
    return pointer;
}
while(cursor!=NULL && strcmp(pointer->name,cursor->name)<0){
    previous = cursor;
    cursor = cursor->next;
}
if(previous!=NULL)
    previous->next = pointer;
pointer->next = cursor;
return people;
}
```

in this way you insert the new element after the first element with a name alphabetically lower and you link it with the next element.

Comment: Hmm...it appears that this gives me a segmentation fault :/

Comment: The problem appears to be with previous->next = pointer; Also, I am calling the insert_sorted method like this:                                for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
  {
    people = insert_sorted(people, names[i], ages[i]);
  }

Comment: Same problem :( segmentation fault because of line 98 (previous->next = pointer;) Really weird :/

Comment: A check is needed before previous->next in the case the element is to be set at the beginning of the list ;-) try now.

Comment: Yes! :D The Segmentation fault is gone. The only problem now is that for some reason it skips a value (in my case the 3rd one). Any ideas why it is doing that?

Comment: Maybe because previous must be initialized to people. I made an edit. Sorry for errors, I'm compiling only with my mind :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42158/discussion-between-sarah-and-hal9000)

Answer (score 0):

I've done nothing to this code beyond naming things correctly, eliminating redundant comments, and running it through `indent -linux`.

```
struct person *insert_sorted(struct person *people, char *name, int age)
{
        struct person *newperson = malloc(sizeof *newperson);
        if (newperson == NULL) {
                printf("The program could not allocate memory ");
                exit(-1);
        }

        strcpy(newperson->name, name);
        newperson->age = age;
        newperson->next = people;

        if (people == NULL) {
                newperson->next = people;
                return newperson;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) {
                people = people->next;
                if (people->next == NULL)
                        return people;
        }

        return newperson;
}
```

A couple of things pop out immediately:

- it's not clear that you'e initializing all of `*newperson`.  Safest is `newperson = calloc(1, sizeof *newperson)`, then readers don't even have to think about it, always a good result.
- you don't show the structure definition, but you're not checking whether the inbound name fits in the storage at newperson->name -- and if newperson->name is a pointer, you've allocated none for it at all.
- there's a redundant assignment to newperson->next, raising the opposite question, of whether there's something not apparent or perhaps missing that makes it necessary.
- I don't see where in here you're comparing key values.